# Only getting value of one row back from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create **a simple cart** system for my online shop. In order to store add the items the user selects to the cart, I have created an **add to cart** button under my items. My goal is that when this button is pressed the **uid** that is saved in my database, of the item selected is saved on a current session. However, when I press this button, for some reason it is always the id of the third item **(cabuid 3)** that gets saved onto the session, regardless of which item I add to cart.
[Here is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ7jq.png)

**index.php** file

```
<form  style="border:1px solid #ccc" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['add'])){
    print_r($_POST['product_id']);
}

include __DIR__.'../includes/dbh.includes.php';
   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM boots";
$gotResults = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if($gotResults) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($gotResults)>0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($gotResults)){
?>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']?>"  style="width:100%">
                  <div class="container">
                    <h2> 
                      <?php echo $row['cabname']; ?> </h2>
                    <p><?php echo $row['cabdescription']; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $row['cabprice']; ?> € </p>
                    <p><button type="submit" class="button" name="add">Add to cart</button></p>
                    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value="<?php echo $row['cabuid']; ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> 
<?php 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**dbh.includes.php**

```
<?php

$serverName = "localhost";
$dbUsername ="root";
$dbPassword ="";
$dbName = "webvacser";

$connection = mysqli_connect($serverName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Looks like all the form fields have the same `name`. The button _happens_ to be in a div that's shared with the field, but that doesn't matter. Form fields should have unique names.

Comment: You could place your `<form>` inside the `while` loop

Comment: Please share more details. Is this problem really related to MySQL itself? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are right, I did not think of doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could simply make use of the fact that `button` allows to specify a submission value. Put the product ID in there, then you don't need the hidden field, and one single form element around the whole thing is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make `n` forms, one per iteration of the loop

```
<?php 
include __DIR__.'../includes/dbh.includes.php';
   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM boots";
$gotResults = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if($gotResults) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($gotResults)>0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($gotResults)){
?>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']?>"  style="width:100%">
                  <div class="container">
                    <h2> <?php echo $row['cabname']; ?> </h2>
                    <p><?php echo $row['cabdescription']; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $row['cabprice']; ?> € </p>
                    <form style="border:1px solid #ccc" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p><button type="submit" class="button" name="add">Add to cart</button></p>
                    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value="<?php echo $row['cabuid']; ?>">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> 
<?php 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now the 3 forms are unique and when you press the button inside any one of them the correct data from the associated hidden input will be sent to the receiving script